# Скрытие/Раскрытие контента jQuery animate

Tags: jquery, animate

Есть кусок html кода

```
<div class="header">тут контент
    <div class="load-panel" style="opacity:0">тут контент</div>
</div>
```

Написал код для раскрытия блока .load-panel

```
$("#load").on("click", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id")
            , check = $(".header").attr("id");

        if(check) {
            $(".load-panel").animate({
                opacity: 0,
                "margin-top": 0,
                paddingTop: 0,
                paddingBottom: 0,
            }, 200, "linear", function() {

                $(".header").animate({
                    "min-height": 60
                }).attr("id", "");
            });
            return false;
        }

        $(".header").animate({
            "min-height": 400
        }, 200, "linear", function() {
            $( this ).attr("id","open");
            $(".load-panel").css({
                "border-top": '1px solid'
            }).animate({
                opacity: 1,
                "margin-top": 15,
                paddingTop: 30,
                paddingBottom: 30,
                borderColor: "#c0c0c0"
            });
        });
    });
```

Как решить проблему множественных кликов по ссылке раскрыть блок? В случае если кликнуть к примеру 5 раз по ссылке, блок .header возвращается в свое исходное положение, точнее высота его 60px, а блок .load-panel остается незакрытым.

Может быть кто то поможет поправить/усовершенствовать код для более правильного исполнения задачи?

Comment: А что этот код делает? Читал-читал, но что-то запутано все так.  
Может просто проверять, закрыт ли блок .load-panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7a8WW/2/).

```
var flag = 0,
    header = $(".header"),
    loadPanel = $('.load-panel'),
    animParams = {
        0: {
            opacity: 1,
            marginTop: 15,
            paddingTop: 30,
            paddingBottom: 30
        },
        1: {
            opacity: 0,
            marginTop: 0,
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingBottom: 0
        }
    };

$('#load').on('click', function() {
    loadPanel.finish().animate(animParams[flag], 200, 'linear', function() {
        header.animate({
            minHeight: (flag ? 60 : 400)
        });
        flag = flag ? 0 : 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: Интересное решение. Спасибо!

Comment: Только нужно сделать чтобы сначала .header по высоте растягивался, а затем уже раскрывался блок .load-panel
Со скрытием все в порядке, сначала скрывается блок .load-panel, а затем уменьшается .header